# Formatting Complex Numbers

Tags: python, formatting, number-formatting, complex-numbers

For a project in one of my classes we have to output numbers up to five decimal places.It is possible that the output will be a complex number and I am unable to figure out how to output a complex number with five decimal places. For floats I know it is just:

`print "%0.5f"%variable_name`

Is there something similar for complex numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For questions like this, the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/) should be your first stop. Specifically, have a look at the section on [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations). It lists all the string format codes; there isn't one for complex numbers.

What you can do is format the real and imaginary parts of the number separately, using `x.real` and `x.imag`, and print it out in `a + bi` form.

Comment: Just to note, in Python the imaginary part uses `j`.

Answer (score 37):

You could do it as is shown below using the `str.format()` method:

```
>>> n = 3.4+2.3j
>>> n
(3.4+2.3j)
>>> '({0.real:.2f} + {0.imag:.2f}i)'.format(n)
'(3.40 + 2.30i)'
>>> '({c.real:.2f} + {c.imag:.2f}i)'.format(c=n)
'(3.40 + 2.30i)'
```

To make it handle both positive and negative imaginary portions properly, you would need a (even more) complicated formatting operation:

```
>>> n = 3.4-2.3j
>>> n
(3.4-2.3j)
>>> '({0:.2f} {1} {2:.2f}i)'.format(n.real, '+-'[n.imag < 0], abs(n.imag))
'(3.40 - 2.30i)'
```

**Update - Easier Way**

Although you **cannot** use `f` as a presentation type for complex numbers using the string formatting operator `%`:

```
n1 = 3.4+2.3j
n2 = 3.4-2.3j

try:
    print('test: %.2f' % n1)
except Exception as exc:
    print('{}: {}'.format(type(exc).__name__, exc))
```

Output:

```
TypeError: float argument required, not complex
```

You **can** however use it with complex numbers via the `str.format()` method. This isn't explicitly documented, but is implied by the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?highlight=formatting#format-specification-mini-language) documentation which just says:

> `'f'`  Fixed point. Displays the number as a fixed-point number. The default precision is `6`.

. . .so it's easy to overlook.
In concrete terms, the following works in both Python 2.7.14 and 3.4.6:

```
print('n1: {:.2f}'.format(n1))
print('n2: {:.2f}'.format(n2))
```

Output:

```
n1: 3.10+4.20j
n2: 3.10-4.20j
```

This doesn't give you quite the control the code in my original answer does, but it's certainly much more concise (and handles both positive and negative imaginary parts automatically).

**Update 2 - *f-strings***

[Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) (aka *f-strings*) were added in Python 3.6, which means it could also be done like this in that version or later:

```
print(f'n1: {n1:.2f}')  # -> n1: 3.40+2.30j
print(f'n2: {n2:.3f}')  # -> n2: 3.400-2.300j
```

In Python 3.8.0, support for an `=` specifier [was added](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging) to f-strings, allowing you to write:

```
print(f'{n1=:.2f}')  # -> n1=3.40+2.30j
print(f'{n2=:.3f}')  # -> n2=3.400-2.300j
```

Comment: What if the imaginary part is negative?

Comment: @Peter: To handle both positive and negative imaginary portions you could use `'({0.real:.2f} {0.imag:+.2f}j)'.format(n)`.

Comment: That would produce, for example, `(3.40 -2.30j)`. What if you want `(3.40 - 2.30j)`?

Comment: @Peter: For that you'd need something like `'({0:.2f} {1} {2:.2f}j)'.format(n.real, '+' if n.imag >= 0 else '-', abs(n.imag))`. If you have further questions please post them as such rather than as comments.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to help you correct and improve your answer. With a negative imaginary part it will print, for example, `(3.49 + -2.30j)`.

Comment: The `abs(n.imag)` should take care of that.

Comment: Yes, I know the comment is correct. But the answer isn't. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer.  It's frustrating to come to a difficult string formatting thread and have everyone link the docs (which are super unhelpful really), even after admitting that there's no way shown in the docs.  I really don't get why python doesn't have something like:

'0.2cf' to mean complex float, that would work just like a normal float...

Comment: @Adam: I can only speculate but from what I've read it sounds like it might be because Python was originally just a "hobby" programming project of its creator, so handling complex numbers was probably not a high priority -- although by now one would think it might be a little better at doing it.

Answer (score 5):

Neither [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) - i.e. the modulo (`%`) operator) -
nor the newer `str.format()` [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) support complex types.
However it is possible to call the `__format__` method of all built in numeric types directly.
Here is an example:

```
>>> i = -3 # int
>>> l = -33L # long (only Python 2.X)
>>> f = -10./3 # float
>>> c = - 1./9 - 2.j/9 # complex
>>> [ x.__format__('.3f') for x in (i, l, f, c)]
['-3.000', '-33.000', '-3.333', '-0.111-0.222j']
```

Note, that this works well with negative imaginary parts too.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> n = 3.4 + 2.3j
>>> print '%05f %05fi' % (n.real, n.imag)
3.400000 2.300000i
```

Comment: Changed to `'%05f %+05fi' % (n.real, n.imag)` it always shows the imaginary part's sign which looks mathematically nice in both cases: `3.400000 +2.300000i` and `3.400000 -2.300000i`.

Answer (score 1):

As of Python 2.6 you can define how objects of your own classes respond to format strings.  So, you can define a subclass of `complex` that can be formatted.  Here's an example:

```
>>> class Complex_formatted(complex):
...     def __format__(self, fmt):
...         cfmt = "({:" + fmt + "}{:+" + fmt + "}j)"
...         return cfmt.format(self.real, self.imag)
... 
>>> z1 = Complex_formatted(.123456789 + 123.456789j)
>>> z2 = Complex_formatted(.123456789 - 123.456789j)
>>> "My complex numbers are {:0.5f} and {:0.5f}.".format(z1, z2)
'My complex numbers are (0.12346+123.45679j) and (0.12346-123.45679j).'
>>> "My complex numbers are {:0.6f} and {:0.6f}.".format(z1, z2)
'My complex numbers are (0.123457+123.456789j) and (0.123457-123.456789j).'
```

Objects of this class behave exactly like `complex` numbers except they take more space and operate more slowly; reader beware.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)  # Rounds up to 2 decimals all float expressions
```

I've successfully printed my complexfloat's expressions:

```
# Show poles and zeros
print( "zeros = ", zeros_H , "\n")
print( "poles = ", poles_H )
```

out before:

```
zeros =  [-0.8       +0.6j -0.8       -0.6j -0.66666667+0.j ] 

poles =  [-0.81542318+0.60991027j -0.81542318-0.60991027j -0.8358203 +0.j        ]
```

out after:

```
zeros =  [-0.8 +0.6j -0.8 -0.6j -0.67+0.j ] 

poles =  [-0.82+0.61j -0.82-0.61j -0.84+0.j  ]
```