# How to limit decimal places when using complex numbers

Tags: python, formatting, complex-numbers

```
sqrtnum_ = 0
sqrtnum_ = cmath.sqrt(snum_)

print "Using cmath.sqrt:"
print "    sqrt(", snum_, ") =      ", '%.12f' %sqrtnum_
```

How can I limit the number of decimal places. Normally I would use the above but it does not work with complex numbers

Comment: Can't You just do `"%.12f + %.12f j "%(sqrtnum_.real,sqrtnum_.imag)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `imag` and `real` attributes of a complex number to get their respective values.

```
>>> a = cmath.sqrt(-1000)
>>> "%.12f + %.12fj"%(a.real,a.imag)
'0.000000000000 + 31.622776601684j'
```

This works for completely real numbers also

```
>>> a = cmath.sqrt(1000)
>>> "%.12f + %.12fj"%(a.real,a.imag)
'31.622776601684 + 0.000000000000j'
```

Comment: Can you specify a varible in the decimals? `"%(variable)f + %.12fj"%(a.real,a.imag)`

Comment: @MarioGalván Yep, that is possible. For e.g: you need it `x` decimal places for real and `y` for the other, then you can do `("%%.%df + %%.%dfj"%(x,y))%(a.real,a.imag)`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have also tried using this: `"%.*f + %.12fj"%(a.real,a.imag)` and it works too.

Comment: @MarioGalván You are welcome, There are surely numerous ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a duplicate of [Formatting Complex Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746143/formating-complex-numbers-in-python)

hopefully that helps!

(would have followed duplicate marking/commenting/etc protocol, but lack the rep for it)