# Can't convert complex to float on python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I write this code for uri online judge(problem no.1036)...It is an Bhaskara's formula...

```
import cmath
A,B,C=input().split()
A = float(A)
B = float(B)
C = float(C)
D = (B*B)-(4*A*C)
if((D== -D)|(A==0)):
    print("Impossivel calcular")

else:
    T = cmath.sqrt(D)
    x1 = (-B+T)/(2*A)
    x2 = (-B-T)/(2*A)
    print("R1 = %.5f" %x1)
    print("R2 = %.5f" %x2)
```

but when i submit this program...that runtime error occured...

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "Main.py", line 14, in
    print("R1 = %.5f" %x1)
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
Command exited with non-zero status (1)
```

please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting Complex Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746143/formatting-complex-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is just that your format string is for `floats` and not for complex numbers. something like this will work:

```
print('{:#.3} '.format(5.1234 + 4.123455j))
# (5.12+4.12j)
```

or - more explicit:

```
print('{0.real:.3f} + {0.imag:.3f}i'.format(5.123456789 + 4.1234556547643j))
# 5.123 + 4.123i
```

you may want to have a look at the [format specification mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?highlight=formatting#format-specification-mini-language).

`#` as format specifier will not work with the old-style `%` formatting...

then there are more issues with your code:

```
if((D== -D)|(A==0)):
```

why not `if D==0:`? and for that it might be better to use [`cmath.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/cmath.html#cmath.isclose).

then: `|` is a bit-wise operator the way you use it; you may want to replace it with `or`.

your `if` statement could look like this:

```
if D == 0 or A == 0:
# or maybe
# if D.isclose(0) or A.isclose():
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using `sqrt` imported from `cmath` is that it outputs a `complex` number, which cannot be converted to `float`. If you are calculating a `sqrt` from positive number, use `math` library (see below).

```
>>> from cmath import sqrt
>>> sqrt(2)
(1.4142135623730951+0j)
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> sqrt(2)
1.4142135623730951
```