# printoptions formatter not working for a single element of an array of complex numbers

Tags: python, scipy, format, numpy-ndarray

I can't understand why this formatter doesn't format a `complex128`:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

A = sp.diags([1, -2, 1], [1, 0, -1], shape=[3, 3], format='csc')
evals, evecs = sp.linalg.eigs(A, k=1, which='LM')

with np.printoptions(formatter={'complex_kind': '{:.2f}'.format}):
    print (evals, evals[0])
```

This code displays a one-element numpy.ndarray, then the element. The formatter is used for the array, not for the element alone:

```
[-3.41+0.00j] (-3.4142135623730954+0j)
```

Types involved:

```
type(evals): numpy.ndarray
evals.dtype: dtype('complex128')
type(evals[0]): numpy.complex128
```

Any clue appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746143/formatting-complex-numbers does this help you

Comment: `evals[0]` is a python complex, not a `numpy` array.

Comment: `evals[0]` is a python complex, not a `numpy` array.

Comment: @hpaulj: `evals` being an array of complexes, indeed `evals[0]` is a complex. The question is why this complex isn't formatted by `formatter={'complex_kind': '{:.2f}'.format}`

Comment: It is not a **numpy** complex.  You have to use python formatting directly.

Comment: @hpaulj: "*evals[0] is a python complex [...] not a numpy complex*": Are you sure, as `type(evals[0]` returns `numpy.complex128`. Even if that was true I wouldn't understand why `print (evals, evals[0])` would process the two arguments differently.

Comment: It is a `numpy.complex128`, but the settings of `printoptions` only apply when printing an array, not a numpy scalar.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Thanks. If you are right (which would explain), then there is a problem with the description of [set_printoptions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions): "*These options determine the way **floating point numbers, arrays and other NumPy objects** are displayed.*" which lists arrays as one of the possible objects to format. Do you have another reference stating the scope of the options? Found [this post](https://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion%40scipy.org/msg49594.html) about this confusion.

Comment: There is another discussion of the issue here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11048

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Yes, that's definitely the explanation, in this page, there is also [this strange behavior, by stefanv](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11048) (cannot link to comment directly). It's ok for me, but I'd be happy to select your answer if you have time to post one. It could be useful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings of [`numpy.printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.printoptions.html) and [`numpy.set_printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) control how NumPy prints *arrays*.  They do not affect how NumPy scalars (such as `numpy.complex128`, `numpy.float32`, etc) are printed.

For example,

```
In [14]: np.set_printoptions(precision=3)                                       

In [15]: np.array([np.pi])  # A 1-d array.                                                                                          
Out[15]: array([3.142])

In [16]: np.array(np.pi)    # A 0-d array (aka a scalar array)                                                                        
Out[16]: array(3.142)

In [17]: np.float64(np.pi)  # A scalar float64. Output is not controlled by the print options                                       
Out[17]: 3.141592653589793
```

See [github issue 11048](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11048) (and the links given there) on the NumPy github site for discussions of this topic.

Comment: And yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65036864/printoptions-formatter-not-working-for-a-single-element-of-an-array-of-complex-n says: "These options determine the way floating point numbers, arrays and other NumPy objects are displayed." So I guess the docs are wrong.

It appears that `reprlib` also cannot affect numpy floats, so basically there's no way to print them with a smaller precision when they are in a nested container?