# Remove parenthesis from complex numbers-python

Tags: python

Is it possible to remove parentheses when is printed a complex number in pytthon?.  I would like to print several complex numbers in python, for example as;

```
for i in range(100):
    n=i+1j
    print(n)
```

but in this case any complex number is printed as (i+1j), could I remove theses parentheses?. Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: This may help: [Formatting Complex Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746143/formatting-complex-numbers)

Comment: You could either create a type that implements a different `__str__` and `__repr__`, but you should probably just format while printing, as @sj95126 suggests.

Comment: You can also quickly access the real and imaginary components of the complex type via `n.real` and `n.imag` respectively which is useful for formatting when printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `n` object defines a `__str__` method which is called when `print` tries to convert it to a string. You can access the parts individually if you need to print them differently. For example, to print just the real, then just the imaginary part:

```
for i in range(100):
    n = i + 1j
    print(n.real, n.imag)
```

This output gives:

```
0.0 1.0
1.0 1.0
2.0 1.0
3.0 1.0
...
```

So the real and imaginary parts are being interpreted as `float` now instead of `complex`, but you still have the trailing `.0` which you might not want. If you know everything is an `int`, you can change the formatting:

```
for i in range(100):
    n = i + 1j
    print(int(n.real), int(n.imag))
```

Or, you can ask python to guess what the best format will be:

```
for i in range(100):
    n = i + 1j
    print(f"{n.real:g}", f"{n.imag:g}")
```